# Toggle attribute within for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating buttons from an array. When one button is clicked, it hides the other buttons and the button's attribute changes from 'aria-pressed="false"' to 'aria-pressed="true"'. Clicking the button a second time is supposed to undo everything (show all the buttons and change the clicked button's attribute back to "false"). Clicking a button twice currently shows all buttons again, but the attribute remains 'aria-pressed="true"'

Does this need to be built a different way? Or is there a fix using the current approach?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var markerArray = [];

    markerArray.push({ 
        markerAlternativeName: 'Study',
        markerId: 'study'
    });
    markerArray.push({ 
        markerAlternativeName: 'Relax',
        markerId: 'relax'
    });
    markerArray.push({ 
        markerAlternativeName: 'Eat',
        markerId: 'eat'
    });
    markerArray.push({
        markerAlternativeName: 'Gather with friends',
        markerId: 'gather'
    });

    for (var l in markerArray) {
        //build nav
        $('div.buttons').append('<button class="bttn" id="' + markerArray[l].markerId + '" tabindex="0" aria-pressed="false">' + markerArray[l].markerAlternativeName + '</button>');
        
        var markerID = markerArray[l].markerId;

        (function (mrkr) {

            //create click actions  
            $('#'+ mrkr ).on("click", function () {
                console.log("Clicked button: " + mrkr);
                $('.bttn').toggle().attr("aria-pressed","false");
                $('#'+ mrkr).show().attr('aria-pressed','true');
            });

        }(markerID))
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons"></div>
```

Comment: If you want to toggle, why not use a class instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need to toggle the `aria-pressed` and visibility attributes a little more carefully.

I created a `$mrkr` variable that is a jQuery object of the currently pressed button. This will always be visible when it is clicked, so you only have to toggle the `aria-pressed` attribute based on whether it was previously set to `true` or `false`.

There is also now a `$bttn` jQuery object has buttons other than the clicked one. These buttons are always `toggle()`ed, but there is no need to set their `aria-pressed` attribute, since it will already be set to `false`.

NOTE: There are probably several ways to clean up this snippet further. I intentionaly stuck to the original code as much as possible to focus on what was breaking the `aria-pressed` attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var markerArray = [];

    markerArray.push({ 
        markerAlternativeName: 'Study',
        markerId: 'study'
    });
    markerArray.push({ 
        markerAlternativeName: 'Relax',
        markerId: 'relax'
    });
    markerArray.push({ 
        markerAlternativeName: 'Eat',
        markerId: 'eat'
    });
    markerArray.push({
        markerAlternativeName: 'Gather with friends',
        markerId: 'gather'
    });

    for (var l in markerArray) {
        //build nav
        $('div.buttons').append('<button class="bttn" id="' + markerArray[l].markerId + '" tabindex="0" aria-pressed="false">' + markerArray[l].markerAlternativeName + '</button>');
        
        var markerID = markerArray[l].markerId;

        (function (mrkr) {

            //create click actions  
            $('#'+ mrkr ).on("click", function () {
                console.log("Clicked button: " + mrkr);
                
                var $mrkr = $('#'+ mrkr);
                var $bttn = $('.bttn').not($mrkr);
                
                $mrkr.attr("aria-pressed", $mrkr.attr("aria-pressed")=="true"?"false":"true");
                $bttn.toggle();
            });

        })(markerID)
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend performing click actions conditionally, depending on the `aria-pressed` state of the clicked button.

Also, rather than binding a handler to each button from within your loop, I suggest binding one click handler to all `.bttn` elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $container = $('.buttons');
  var markers = [];

  markers.push({
    name: 'Study',
    id: 'study'
  }, {
    name: 'Relax',
    id: 'relax'
  }, {
    name: 'Eat',
    id: 'eat'
  }, {
    name: 'Gather with friends',
    id: 'gather'
  });

  //build nav
  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
    $('<button>', {
      'class': 'bttn',
      'id': marker.id,
      'tabindex': 0,
      'aria-pressed': 'false',
      'text': marker.name
    }).appendTo($container);
  });

  //create click actions
  var $buttons = $('.bttn');

  $buttons.on("click", function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.attr("aria-pressed") != 'true') {
      $buttons.hide().attr("aria-pressed", "false");
      $this.show().attr('aria-pressed', 'true');
    } else {
      $buttons.show().attr("aria-pressed", "false");
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons"></div>
```